# Copy specific files in a all Directory with python

Tags: python, path, operating-system

I found out how to do it with this script:

```
import os, sys, shutil, glob

if not os.path.exists('Files'):
    os.makedirs('Files')

source_dir = os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop")
dest_dir = 'Files'
try:
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source_dir):
        for file in filenames:
            (shortname, extension) = os.path.splitext(file)
            if extension == ".txt" :
                shutil.copy2(os.path.join(root,file), os.path.join(dest_dir,   
                             os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root,file),source_dir)))

except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
```

But, it only copies the files in the path and not the in sub-folders
So for example here it copies the desktop .txt files, but it does not copy the files in the folders.

Thanks, have a good day.

Comment: Take a look at [shutil.copytree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree). "Recursively copy an entire directory tree rooted at src to a directory named dst and return the destination directory. dirs_exist_ok dictates whether to raise an exception in case dst or any missing parent directory already exists."

Comment: Probably not the problem.  But on MacOS at least, it's `os.environ["HOME"]`.  You're sure you're in the right directory?